# Can't edit media Image from within node edit

Tags: 8, media

I'm using Media and the Media Library (yes I know this is experimental). And all of the sudden I'm not able to edit my added image when I'm editing a node. In an earlier stage of the website I was able to edit the image by clicking the name. The name was blue (a link).

But now the name is black.
[image: Screenshot of Node Field]

Even though I'm the admin I checked the permissions but all looks fine. And when I go to my Media Library I am able to change the Images with the name link.

[image]

I'm new to Media and the Media Library so I was wondering if there is a setting I've missed? Or if there is a common bug I couldn't find online. Hope someone can help me figuring out what the problem is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is this module, but it's only in dev release. https://www.drupal.org/project/media_library_edit.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but its not really what I want. I thought the blue link in de node edit page made it possible to edit it on the same page. Not linking to a new page. Or am I hallucinating?